# Error when running trigger - Error Code: 1054 Unknown Column 'action' in field list

Tags: sql

When I run the below `UPDATE` command after I run the trigger, I get the following error

> Error Code: 1054 Unknown Column 'action' in field list

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_9
BEFORE UPDATE ON Customers
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Customers

    SET action = 'update',
        Email = NEW.Email,
        CustomerID = NEW.CustomerID;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

UPDATE Customers
SET Email = 'Update'
WHERE CustomerID = 12345;

SELECT * FROM Customers
```

Comment: You must have checked your table `Customers` to make sure it has a column named `action`. Please confirm.

Comment: It looks like your trigger is used for auditing changes to the `Customer.Email` field. Are you sure you want to `insert` that info into your `Customer` table and not maybe a different (audit) table, maybe named something like `Customer_Audit` or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for that. I changed the code greatly. While the trigger is now working it will only work once. I get the error that duplicate value for the primary key. Updated code in next comment

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER T05
AFTER UPDATE ON Customers
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 
UPDATE HistoryTable
SET
LastName = OLD.LastName,
FirstName = OLD.FirstName,
Country = OLD.Country,
Phone = OLD.Phone,
Email = OLD.Email,
CustomerID = OLD.CustomerID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;


UPDATE Customers
SET Email = 'Update5'
WHERE CustomerID = 20009

SELECT*FROM Customers

SELECT*FROM HistoryTable

Comment: In your `HistoryTable` make sure your PK is not on `CustomerID`. You will either need 1) a new auto-number col for the PK in your HistoryTable. or 2) add a column to your HistoryTable to track the datetime of each change, and then set the PK for HistoryTable to use a compound PK with CustomerID and the new datetime col.  I usually prefer autonumber because it is easier and guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks tgolish, that worked however my trigger is updating all my columns with the same data in HistoryTable as opposed to just one.

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger1
BEFORE UPDATE ON Customers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO HistoryTable
SET
LastName = OLD.LastName,
FirstName = OLD.FirstName,
County = OLD.County,
Email = OLD.Email,
Phone = OLD.Phone,
CustomerID = OLD.CustomerID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;


UPDATE Customers
SET Email = 'Update77'
WHERE CustomerID = 3;

Comment: Oh, I see now. Decision time: If you want to keep the entire history, then only do INSERTs into your HistoryTable (no updates, because they destroy history). If  you only want to keep 1 (per customer) ... The easy way would be to delete (just 1 customer row) and re-insert to your HistoryTable.  The hard way would be to use logic like `IF Exists(SELECT CustomerID FROM HistoryTable WHERE CustomerID=#####) UPDATE ... ELSE INSERT ...`

Comment: Do you mind if I summarize my comments into an answer below? and would you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trigger is being used for auditing changes to the `Customer.Email` field.  You would be better off inserting that info into a different (audit) table, maybe named something like `Customer_Audit` or something like that.

There are two ways of setting this up:

1) If you want to keep the entire history, then only do INSERTs into your Audit table (no updates, because they destroy history).  In that table, make sure the PK is either a (new) auto-number col (not the CustomerID) or a compound PK consisting of  CustomerID + a (new) datetime col. I usually recommend autonumber because it is easier and guarantees uniqueness.

-or-

2) If you only want to keep 1 history record per customer, the easy way would be to delete (just 1 customer row) and re-insert into to your Audit table. The hard way would be to use logic like `IF Exists(SELECT CustomerID FROM HistoryTable WHERE CustomerID=#####) UPDATE ... ELSE INSERT ...`